# How to limit chart js to display existing axis values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, bar-chart

I'm adding Chart js to my React project where I need to display data per day, everything seems to be working fine, except when I add pan functionality, the chart scrolls left/right and adds some random dates.
for example this is the data I want to display:

```
data: [
          { x: "2021-01-01", y: 10 },
          { x: "2021-01-02", y: 20 },
          { x: "2021-01-03", y: 20 },
          { x: "2021-01-04", y: 20 },
          { x: "2021-01-05", y: 20 }
        ]
```

this is how chart looks if I scroll left
[image]

I don't understand where **Dec 31** is coming from, also if I scroll to the right, I'm getting additional days that are not defined in the data( January 6, 7 etc). How can I restrict the pan to scroll according to the provided date range only? ( don't pan to Dec 31 or January 6)
[image]

My code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/nifty-shadow-2jfdfk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

My code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  Title,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  TimeScale,
  BarElement
} from "chart.js";
import "chartjs-adapter-date-fns";
import { enUS } from "date-fns/locale";

ChartJS.register(
  BarElement,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  zoomPlugin,
  TimeScale
);

import zoomPlugin from "chartjs-plugin-zoom";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const options = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 0
      },
      line: {
        borderWidth: 1.5
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: "time",
        time: {
          unit: "day"
        },

        ticks: {
          color: "rgba( 0, 0, 1)"
        },
        grid: {
          color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)"
        }
      },
      y: {
        ticks: {
          color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)"
        },
        grid: {
          color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)"
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      zoom: {
        pan: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: "x",
          speed: 10
        }
      }
    }
  };

  const data = {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [
          { x: "2021-01-01", y: 10 },
          { x: "2021-01-02", y: 20 },
          { x: "2021-01-03", y: 20 },
          { x: "2021-01-04", y: 20 },
          { x: "2021-01-05", y: 20 }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
  const canvasRef = useRef();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Bar
        ref={canvasRef}
        options={options}
        data={data}
        height={null}
        width={null}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing good.

The Dec 31 date is added to the chart because the x-axis time scale is starting from December 31, 2020 by default, which is the beginning of the week that includes January 1, 2021. The additional days (e.g., January 6, 7, etc.) that appear when you pan to the right are added because the chart is using the zoom plugin, which allows the user to pan beyond the range of the data.
To restrict the pan to scroll according to the provided date range only, you can set the min and max values of the x-axis time scale.

The fixed code :

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  Title,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  TimeScale,
  BarElement
} from "chart.js";
import "chartjs-adapter-date-fns";
import { enUS } from "date-fns/locale";

ChartJS.register(
  BarElement,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  zoomPlugin,
  TimeScale
);

import zoomPlugin from "chartjs-plugin-zoom";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const startDate = new Date("2021-01-01");
  const endDate = new Date("2021-01-05");

  const options = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 0
      },
      line: {
        borderWidth: 1.5
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: "time",
        time: {
          unit: "day"
        },
        ticks: {
          color: "rgba(0, 0, 1)"
        },
        grid: {
          color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)"
        },
        min: startDate,
        max: endDate
      },
      y: {
        ticks: {
          color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)"
        },
        grid: {
          color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)"
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      zoom: {
        pan: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: "x",
          speed: 10,
          limits: {
            x: { min: startDate, max: endDate }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  const data = {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [
          { x: "2021-01-01", y: 10 },
          { x: "2021-01-02", y: 20 },
          { x: "2021-01-03", y: 20 },
          { x: "2021-01-04", y: 20 },
          { x: "2021-01-05", y: 20 }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  const canvasRef = useRef();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Bar
        ref={canvasRef}
        options={options}
        data={data}
        height={null}
        width={null}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've added startDate and endDate variables which define the range of the chart, and set the minimum and maximum values for the x-axis to these variables. Additionally, I added a limits option to the zoom.pan configuration to restrict panning to the defined date range.

Hopefully It will help you.
Kind regards.